# Calculating ball deflection angle when colliding with paddle in brick slayer game

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is my code:

```
void Draw()
{
    int x = 59;
    int y = 500;
    int temp = x;
    int colour;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                colour = 2;
            else
                colour = 3;
            DrawRectangle(x, y, 65, 25, colors[colour]);
            x += 67;
        }
        x = temp;
        y -= 39;
    }
    DrawRectangle(tempx, 0, 85, 12, colors[5]);
    DrawCircle(templx, temply, 10, colors[7]);
}

// This function will be called automatically by this frequency: 1000.0 / FPS
void Animate()
{
    templx +=5;
    temply +=5;
    /*if(templx>350)
        templx-=300;
    if(temply>350)
        temply-=300;*/
    glutPostRedisplay(); // Once again call the Draw member function
}
// This function is called whenever the arrow keys on the keyboard are pressed...
//
```

I am using OpenGL for this project. The function `Draw()` is used to print the bricks, slider, and the ball. The `Animate()` function is called automatically by the frequency given in the code. As it can be seen, I have incremented the values of `templx` and `temply`, but the ball goes out of screen as it crosses its limit. I have to deflect the ball if it collides with the paddle or the wall. What can I do to achieve this? All the conditions that I have used by now do not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you would like to have a ball that is bouncing from the edges of your window. (For this answer I will ignore the slider, finding collision with the slider is very similar to finding collision with the walls).

`templx` and `temply` pair is position of your ball. I don't know what is the 3rd argument of `DrawCircle` function so I will assume that it is the radius. Let `wwidth` and `wheight` be width and height of a game window. Note that this magic constant `5` is, in fact, a velocity of the ball. Now ball is moving from upper left corner to lower right corner of your window. If you change `5` to `-5` it will move from lower right corner to upper left corner.

Let's introduce two more variables `vx` and `vy` - velocity on x axis and velocity on y axis. The initial values will be 5 and 5. Now notice that when ball hits the right edge of the window it doesn't change its vertical velocity, it is still moving up/down but it changes its horizontal velocity from left->right to right->left. So if the `vx` was `5`, after hitting the right edge of the window we should change it to `-5`.

The next problem is how to find out if we hit the edge of the window or not.
Note that the right-most point on the ball has the position `templx + radius` and the left-most point on the ball has the position `templx - radius` etc. Now to find out if we hit the wall or not we should just compare this values with window dimensions.

```cpp
// check if we hit right or left edge
if (templx + radius >= wwidth || templx - radius <= 0) {
    vx = -vx;
}
// check if we hit top or bottom edge
if (temply + radius >= wheight || temply - radius <= 0) {
    vy = -vy;
}

// update position according to velocity
templx += vx;
temply += vy;
```